How to conditionally end transaction with rollback or commit?
I start transaction, execute some data updates and at the end I check if the outcome make sense (for me).
The last step would to execute commit if it does, or rollback if it does not. My knowledge of sqlite is rusty, all I can find is conditional for expressions, not for commands, so how can I end transaction conditionally?
Just to clarify, the data always make sense for database constraints, so I cannot rely on approach "let's commit always, and in case of the problem, DB itself will rollback". I have to make this decision -- rollback or commit.
Actual, but shortened, code (it is of course not finished). There are more updates/swaps like this:
PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = true;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE language SET id=3 - id WHERE id < 3;

iif(exists(select 1 from language where id = '1' AND code = 'PL') AND exists(select 1 from language where id = '2' AND code = 'EN'), commit, rollback);

PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = false;


Rollbacks should (generally) not be happening due to business logic.  Rather, rollbacks happen when there is a failure in the transaction.  If you don't want certain updates to happen, then add logic to the updates.

@TimBiegeleisen This was my first thought, but I realized that it would mean writing a lot of code (basically multiple conditions, for every update), so it is cheaper for me -- human -- to write this once and for good.

You might want to include actual code here.

@TimBiegeleisen I don't think this is useful (current code), but no problem in doing so as well :-). Updated :-).

Just as a suggestion/comment, you could rewrite your update with the restrictions at the end as:
UPDATE language
SET id = 3 - id
WHERE
    id < 3 AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM language WHERE id = 1 AND code = 'PL') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM language WHERE id = 2 AND code = 'EN');

As I mentioned in a comment above, rollbacks are really for undoing an entire transaction because of some critical failure, not due a business logic condition.  For business logic, you should rely on the SQL language.
Another option, refactoring to make use of a CTE:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM language WHERE id = 1 AND code = 'PL') AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM language WHERE id = 2 AND code = 'EN')
)

UPDATE language
SET id = 3 - id
WHERE id < 3 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte);


Yes, I am doing this now but simply because I cannot find way to make conditional rollback/commit. In general it is this debate "way more readable, more suited for specific case, but not along guidelines" vs "kosher, painful, recommended, bloated" and you chose second just because it is common wisdom :-) Well, I am not in this camp.

@greenoldman I have updated to show how you can perhaps more succinctly do this using a CTE.  I keep kosher, by the way!

Oh, many, many, thanks! While I still prefer procedural approach like if ... then ... do-those-updates this actually helps a lot because it changes the logic in preferred way. The condition is pre-computed, and it is "fixed" while updating, while update with where would self changing its condition.
